# Fixed: Amazon Ad Error : Adcode values too long D.<computed> @ onejs?MarketPlace

Tags: affiliate, amazon-marketplace, amazon-advertising-api

The Amazon Native ad I added on my website displays nothing. Instead, the browser throws an error like so:

```
Error: Adcode values too long D.<computed> @ onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=ab1c2345-d67e-8f90-fg12-34g5h6789i0j:1
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that resolved it for me:

1. Go to the saved ad on your Amazon Associate page.
2. Deselect all the categories from your Ad preferences section.

It seems Amazon has a limit on the categories you can select. In other words, the browser shows the error when you've selected too many categories.

[image: Amazon ad unit setting]